# mongoose document filtering properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have defined a schema like

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  location: { type: String, required: true },
  picture: { type: String, required: true },
  passwordHash: { type: String, required: true },
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpired: Boolean
});
```

I have a REST Endpoint which return list of all users. In that list I want to hide some properties i.e, `passwordHash, resetPasswordToken, resetPasswordExpired`

I defined a custom filter function like below

```
var doFilterUser = function(user) {
  _.omit(user, ['passwordHash', 'resetPasswordToken', 'resetPasswordExpired']);
   user.id = user._id;
   delete user._id;
   delete user.__v;
   return user;
};
```

`_` is lodash

When I check my API is responding with all user properties

This filter function is defined in common helper module and I am calling it like

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user) {
  var filtered = helper.doFilterUser(user);
});
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you still have a mongoose document that conforms to s strict schema. If you want to change that document, then you need to make it a "raw" object without all the additional controls:

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, user) {
  var filtered = helper.doFilterUser(user.toObject());
});
```

So the `.toObject()` method here will return an object in it's raw form. That allows you to manipulate the keys how you wish.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
   You are allowed to access certain values through mongoose.

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, 'firstName lastName email location picture', function(err, user){
  console.log(user);
```

});

You just mention the fields needed, after the query.

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 2):

You can also explicitly direct it not to serve back certain properties. Useful if you don't want to render a hashed password over the wire. The find method would look like this:

```
User.find({}, '-id -__v',function(err,users){
})
```

or

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, '-id -__v',function(err,user){
})
```